# How to resolve package conflicts Fedora 33 openssl-devel libressl-devel

Tags: fedora, dnf

I have Fedora 33 and I want to install the updates with command:

```
sudo dnf update
```

Before confirmation of installation I see that dnf has found dependent package that should be installed: `openssl-devel`

While running transaction test I get an error:

```
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /usr/include/openssl/aes.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/asn1.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/asn1t.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/bio.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/blowfish.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/bn.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/buffer.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/camellia.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/cast.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/cmac.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/cms.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/comp.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/conf.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/conf_api.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/crypto.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/des.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/dh.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/dsa.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/dtls1.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/ec.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/ecdh.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/ecdsa.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/engine.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/err.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/evp.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/hmac.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/idea.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/lhash.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/md4.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/md5.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/modes.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/obj_mac.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/objects.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/ocsp.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/opensslv.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/pem.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/pem2.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/pkcs12.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/pkcs7.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/rand.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/rc2.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/rc4.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/ripemd.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/rsa.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/safestack.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/sha.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/srtp.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/ssl2.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/ssl3.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/stack.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/tls1.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/ts.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/txt_db.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/ui.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/whrlpool.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/x509.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/x509_vfy.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/include/openssl/x509v3.h from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libssl.so from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libcrypto.pc from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libssl.pc from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/pkgconfig/openssl.pc from install of openssl-devel-1:1.1.1k-1.fc33.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libressl-devel-3.2.5-1.x86_64
```

Please help with resolving this issue!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem myself by deleting it from the system.

The command for removing:
`sudo dnf remove libressl-devel`

The `libressl` and `libressl-devel` packages are also available for Fedora, but from the third party "RPM Sphere x86_64" repository. I tried to remove package `libressl-devel` and found that there is only one application on the system that depends on it, which is `terminology` (EFL based terminal emulator). I installed this application earlier and I no longer need it. So I just removed the package `libressl-devel` and `terminology` app that dependent on it.

After removing package `libssl-devel` I was successfully updated my Fedora 33 packages.